# Adding Reverse DNS for Azure Email VM

Tags: email-server, windows-server-2012-r2, azure

I am a fresh user in azure, i created a windows VM and installed hMailServer on it, when i send emails to some recipients i get the following error:

`Remote server replied: 550 5.7.1 Connections not accepted from servers without a valid sender domain.flph396 Fix reverse DNS for 000.00.000.000`

the IP(000.00.000.000) is not my vm IP.

i tried

```
Set-AzureService –ServiceName “contosoapp1” –Description “App1 with Reverse DNS” –ReverseDnsFqdn “contosoapp1.cloudapp.net.”
```

but its not working, i used my vm fqdn and my own a record for mail "mail.myDomain.com" but nothing worked.

Comment: is the address 000.00.000.000 what the message is actually saying or is that what you've redacted to put here?

Comment: Remote server replied: 550 5.7.1 Connections not accepted from servers without a valid sender domain.flph396 Fix reverse DNS for 104.40.149.135